# как очистить пост после передачи данных

Tags: javascript

Имеется скрипт, для сбора информации из полей `email` и `phone`, проблема в том, что после первой передачи, если нужно отредактировать эти поля у других пользователей, в следующий раз передаётся массив с этими данными + новыми. Можно ли очистить `post` после передачи в контроллер или может ещё какие-то есть варианты? Фрагмент кода прилагаю.

```
$(document).on('click', '#edituserback', function() {
var post = {};
post.uid = id;
//post.data = data;
post.ajaxRequest = true;

post.email = [];
  $('input.email').each(function(i,el){
    var val = $(el).val();
    post.email.push(val);
  });

post.phone = [];
  $('input.phone').each(function(i,el){
    var val = $(el).val();
    post.phone.push(val);
  });

var result = sendAjaxRequest({
  url: '/back/editUsers',
  data: post
});
});
```

Comment: post  = {} не подходит?

Comment: сначала тоже так думал, не срабатывает

Comment: А где вы это делаете? После отправки ?

Comment: да, именно после отправки пробовал